# Opencart 2.0.1.1Email

Tags: email, opencart2.x

Another question for the wizard's of society, 
I've been setting up a webstore at www.ecigone.co.uk for sometime now & had numerous problems with our contact form, I have set it up in the back of opencart and also tried to -f, the smtp settings & hostgator's online setup guide. After searching for a few threads on here, i haven't managed to fix this issue & it is causing downtime. If someone could see why or where im going wrong with this form it would help me on countless hours.

Thank-you in advance,

Open cart Version is 2.0.1.1

Answer (score 0):

Well make sure the Store Email in General tab and Mail tab  email are your domain email i.e  xyz@yourdomian.com